# How to minimize validator downtime when moving to a new hardware (server)?

Tags: validator

It’s quite easy to start a new validator from scratch but how do we manage the migration of the validator to a new hardware and minimize down time?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to get your new hardware running as a non voting validator using a secondary identity key.  Then you can switch identities using the method described by mvines here: https://github.com/mvines/validator-Identity-transition-demo

Comment: this answer can be improved by giving a high-level overview of the content behind the link. basically strip out the example parts and just describe the operations and why each step is necessary would be great